# How can I set two loops in python?

Tags: python, loops

Hi I am new to python and right now I am trying to learn how to scrape website. I am practicing the loop function. And here is the question

i) I am using a weather site to get two data: weather and temperature.

ii) In the url of the site, it include the date and city.

The trouble is I can only control one side of loop, I searched the site and did not find an answer.

The following is the code I wrote.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

calday = ["01","02","03","04","05"...."31"]
citylist = ["Newyork","London","Paris"]
for i in range(len(calday)):
for i in range(len(citylist)):
    url="http://websitename.com/localeCode=en_US&complexSearchField="+citylist[i]+"&05%2F"+calday+"2F2015"   # 05%2F01%2F2015 which means 2015-05-01 and the day is replaced by "+calday+" 

    wb_data = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(wb_data.text,'lxml')
    weathers = soup.select('.searchResultsweather')
    temps = soup.select('.searchResultstemp')
    time.sleep(2)
    for temp,weather in zip(temps,weathers):
        data = {
        "temp":temp.get_text(),
        "weather":weather.get_text()
        }
        print (data)
```

I know there is better ways to treat the date module, but right now I am stuck by how to fulfill the two loops and get the result like:

Newyork may1 temp weather

Newyork may2 temp weather

...

Newyork may31 temp weather

and then goes to the same format of London and Paris.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is here:

```
for i in range(len(calday)):
    for i in range(len(citylist)):
```

You are using the same loop variable (`i`) in both loops.  Use a more descriptive name and it will be fixed:

```
for dayidx in range(len(calday)):
    for cityidx in range(len(citylist)):
```

But even better, you don't need to do numeric indexing at all.  Just iterate over the values in the lists:

```
for day in calday:
    for city in citylist:
        url = "http://websitename.com/localeCode=en_US&complexSearchField="+city+"&05%2F"+day+"2F2015"
```

Answer (score 1):

You should fix your indentation and putting different variables here:

```
for i in range(len(calday)):
for i in range(len(citylist)):
```

Change to

```
for i in range(len(calday)):
   for j in range(len(citylist)): #note the j here
```

Python is a language which uses indentation as block. And if you use the same variable for both your calday and citylist, you cannot access them independently.